# Development Rails server that's compatible with both HTTP and HTTPS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, https

My application isn't quite ready to go full SSL so in the meantime, I am allowing SSL but not requiring it. I do require SSL for certain controllers and force redirects to HTTPS for actions in such controllers.

I can start a thin server using SSL via `thin start --ssl`. This works great for SSL testing. However, I cannot have HTTP and HTTPS running simultaneously on the same port. Obviously, this makes testing redirects from HTTP to HTTPS quite frustrating. I can run an Apache or nginx server on top but I don't really want to go through the trouble of doing that in my development environment.

To start two servers, one for SSL and without, I use foreman like so:

```
web: rails server
ssl: thin start --ssl -p 3001
```

This starts the HTTP server on port 3000 and HTTPS server on 3001. Now my question is. How do I create a "smart redirect" policy only on my development environment only such that redirects from HTTP to HTTPS intelligently changes the port from 3000 to 3001? Thanks!